# Deserialize a nested JSON string in AWS Lambda (C#)

Tags: c#, json, aws-lambda

I have a nested JSON string that is passed to a lambda (part of a State Machine).  I need to assign variables to each item in the dictionary which are then used further down the line in the Lambda process (not shown here).  I have been able to write a couple of classes and a void to try and deserialize the json but I don't know how to integrate `DeserialiseJSONString` into the lambda handler `FunctionHandler`.  My familiarity with Python does not seem to help with understanding how to utilize classes/functions here.  Any input would be greatly appreciated.  I am looking for the most simplistic approach possible (if that is possible).  Here's my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]

namespace LambdaFunctionTwo
{
    public class Function
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// A simple hello world function.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input"></param>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string FunctionHandler(NewUserInfo input, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            
            var Status = input.Status;
            var Platform = input.Platform;
            var GatewayID = input.GatewayID;
            var DatasourceID = input.DatasourceID;
            var Modulus = input.Modulus;
            var Exponent = input.Exponent;
            var Time = input.Time;

            LambdaLogger.Log($"Calling function name:   {context.FunctionName}\n");
            LambdaLogger.Log($"status:                  {Status}\n");
            LambdaLogger.Log($"platform:                {Platform}\n");
            LambdaLogger.Log($"gatewayID:               {GatewayID}\n");
            LambdaLogger.Log($"datasourceID:            {DatasourceID}\n");
            LambdaLogger.Log($"modulus:                 {Modulus}\n");
            LambdaLogger.Log($"exponent:                {Exponent}\n");
            LambdaLogger.Log($"time:                    {Time}\n");
            return $"{Platform} has been updated!";
        }
        public class NewUserInfo
        {
            public string Status { get; set; }
            public string Platform { get; set; }
            public string GatewayID { get; set; }
            public string DatasourceID { get; set; }
            public string Modulus { get; set; }
            public string Exponent { get; set; }
            public string Time { get; set; }

            public class user
            {
                public string Platform { get; set; }
                public string GatewayID { get; set; }
                public string DatasourceID { get; set; }
                public string Modulus { get; set; }
                public string Exponent { get; set; }
                public string Time { get; set; }
            }
        }

        public void DeserialiseJSONString(string strJSON)
        {
            var Credentials = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewUserInfo>(strJSON);
            var Status = Credentials.Status;
            var Platform = Credentials.Platform;
            var GatewayID = Credentials.GatewayID;
            var DatasourceID = Credentials.DatasourceID;
            var Modulus = Credentials.Modulus;
            var Exponent = Credentials.Exponent;
            var Time = Credentials.Time;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is what an event being passed into the handler looks like:

```
{
  "status": "message processed",
  "credentials": {
    "platform": "database_platform",
    "gatewayID": "43534-534534g-23423423-1232",
    "datasourceID": "addr3024023-3e423423d-32423423-dfasd",
    "modulus": "thisisssomemodulus34242342342342342346453454125678765978",
    "exponent": "fakeexponent",
    "time": "2021-01-05 15:48:52.417653"
  }
}
```

Please be kind, C# is brand new to me!

## EDIT:

Updated code (build is fine, test fails)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
// demo
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]
//[assembly: Amazon.Lambda.Core.LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]

namespace LambdaFunctionTwo
{
    public class Function
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// A simple hello world function.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input"></param>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            var myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(input);
            var Status = myDeserializedClass.Status;
            var Platform = myDeserializedClass.Credentials.Platform;
            var GatewayID = myDeserializedClass.Credentials.GatewayID;
            var DatasourceID = myDeserializedClass.Credentials.DatasourceID;
            var Modulus = myDeserializedClass.Credentials.Modulus;
            var Exponent = myDeserializedClass.Credentials.Exponent;
            var Time = myDeserializedClass.Credentials.Time;

            LambdaLogger.Log($"Calling function name:   {context.FunctionName}\n");
            LambdaLogger.Log($"status:                  {Status}\n");
            LambdaLogger.Log($"platform:                {Platform}\n");
            LambdaLogger.Log($"gatewayID:               {GatewayID}\n");
            LambdaLogger.Log($"datasourceID:            {DatasourceID}\n");
            LambdaLogger.Log($"modulus:                 {Modulus}\n");
            LambdaLogger.Log($"exponent:                {Exponent}\n");
            LambdaLogger.Log($"time:                    {Time}\n");
            return $"{myDeserializedClass} has been updated!";
        }
        public class Credentials
        {
            public string Platform { get; set; }
            public string GatewayID { get; set; }
            public string DatasourceID { get; set; }
            public string Modulus { get; set; }
            public string Exponent { get; set; }
            public string Time { get; set; }
        }

        public class Root
        {
            public string Status { get; set; }
            public Credentials Credentials { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
System.Exception: Error deserializing the input JSON to type String at Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.Runtime.LambdaExecutor.BuildParameters(ExecutionRequest request, ILambdaContext context) in C:\codebase\aws-lambda-dotnet\Tools\LambdaTestTool\src\Amazon.Lambda.TestTool\Runtime\LambdaExecutor.cs:line 214
   at Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.Runtime.LambdaExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ExecutionRequest request) in C:\codebase\aws-lambda-dotnet\Tools\LambdaTestTool\src\Amazon.Lambda.TestTool\Runtime\LambdaExecutor.cs:line 52
---------------- Inner 1 Exception ------------
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.Runtime.LambdaExecutor.BuildParameters(ExecutionRequest request, ILambdaContext context) in C:\codebase\aws-lambda-dotnet\Tools\LambdaTestTool\src\Amazon.Lambda.TestTool\Runtime\LambdaExecutor.cs:line 210
---------------- Inner 2 Exception ------------
Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.JsonSerializerException: Error converting the Lambda event JSON payload to a string. JSON strings must be quoted, for example "Hello World" in order to be converted to a string: The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.
   at Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream requestStream)
---------------- Inner 3 Exception ------------
System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& readStack, Utf8JsonReader& reader, Exception ex)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader, ReadStack& readStack)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ParseCore(ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream requestStream)
---------------- Inner 4 Exception ------------
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot get the value of a token type 'StartObject' as a string.
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.GetString()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.JsonConverterString.Read(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfoNotNullable`4.OnRead(ReadStack& state, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo.Read(JsonTokenType tokenType, ReadStack& state, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader, ReadStack& readStack)
```

Comment: You can use https://json2csharp.com/ to create classes for your json

Comment: Thank you Chetan for your assistance, that was something I did not know about!  Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll summarise the question then explain the steps to how I solved this. It's not hard, but there's some tricks newbies might miss.

## Question:

Given some json string, how can I easily deserialize the json string into a class (with children/nested classes, etc)

## Answer:

If we have the json schema (which you did provide), we need to do the following:

- Create some classes (which the data will be persisted too)
- Get the json text
- Deserialize
- Test/Assert.

#### 1 - Create the classes.

Exactly like @chetanRanpariya said, let's use a website that generates these for us. Sure, having a small json might be trivial, but when you get a large json schema, then this saves you HEAPS of time.

Head over to https://json2csharp.com/ and paste your json schema in there, then ask that site to generate the output.

Even in the output they include a sample line of code to actually deserialize this!

[image]

The `root` class is a crap name, so I usually rename it to what the json schema (data) is about. For this example, I'll leave it .. but I would have renamed this to `message` or something.

Okay, so we have our classes generated as C# code .. now let's have a play.

#### 2 Test code

To test out simple C# code, I next use another website called [DotNet Fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/).

In this current "[fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4IOVLD)" you can see that I:

- setup the json message
- deserialize this message into a `root` class.

and the Newtonsoft nuget library is smart enough to figure everything out.

Let's have a look at what I did, so you don't miss out on the tricks, to get this working:

[image]

[image]

In order of the things I did

- Changed it to NET5.0
- Added `Newtonsoft.Json` nuget library (latest version)
- Copy/Pasted the classes over from Json2CSharp. Notice how I've put them just under the Main method, here?
- Added that one line of code from Json2CSharp -> `Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);`
- Noticed that the code doesn't understand `JsonConvert`, so I added that namespace at the top of the file -> `using Newtonsoft.Json;`
- Now, created my fake json text and then passed that value into that deserialize method (notice the name of variable in the method name is `(json)`
- Created a few more lines of code to print out the values of the class which the json was deserialized to.

and voila! we have some json deserialized and working.

Newbie trick: Notice the weird json string? how it is: `var json = @"` ... that `@` makes the string a MULTI-LINE string (also called a *verbatim string literal* or something). When you do this, it's easier to read large swaths of string data over multi lines .. but we have to *double-quote* any `"` (quotes). Normally, we *escape* a quote *inside* a string (e.g. `\"`) but multi-lines don't like any escaping. It's a *literal* string .. hence the name.

Comment: You have done a brilliant job at thoroughly explaining the process, and I'm very appreciative, however, I am still getting an error in the VS Mock Lambda Test Tool with the EDIT in my post.  Any insight as to the issue?

Comment: hi @Matt_Davis - sure, lets see here. The exception you posted includes INNER exceptions. So we do down to the bottom .. and work backwards. The bottom is the _first_ exception .. the one above is the 2nd (based on the first), etc. etc.

Looking at the first (bottom) exception, it is suggesting that there's an error parsing some JSON. Something about a key/value called '`StartObject`' ? Can you please post the FULL json which that test is trying to do. Lets make sure our JSON is the same as the original post and that we have the correct values in it.